# How can I solve this- SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables with left join and want to update by area_id.
**my update code is:**

```
$area = Area::find($id);
            $city_id = DB::table('areas')->where("areas.id", $id)->select("areas.city_id")->join("locations", "areas.city_id", "=", "locations.id")
            ->get();

            if ($area) {
                $area->area_name = $request->input('areaName');
                $area->city_id = $city_id;
                $area->update();
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 200,
                    'message' => $area['areaName'] . ' Updated successfully',
                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 400,
                    'message' => "Area Not found",
                ]);
            }
```

**when I perform this I got an error which is below:**

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{\"city_id\":1}]' for column `laravel_drywashbd`.`areas`.`city_id` at row 1 (SQL: update `areas` set `area_name` = Wari25, `city_id` = [{\"city_id\":1}] where `id` = 3)"
```

How can I solve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your `city_id` created as `datetime` from your migration file but it should be `unsignedBigInteger` instead

another thing this query you should use `first` instead of `get`

```php
$city_id = DB::table('areas')->where("areas.id", $id)->select("areas.city_id")->join("locations", "areas.city_id", "=", "locations.id")->first();
```

Comment: That's what happens when `->get()` is used; `$city_id = DB::table(...)->get()`. Should be replaced with `->first()`, variable renamed to `$city`, then `$area->city_id = $city->id;`. But seconded that the bigger issue is that `city_id` is a `datetime` for some reason 

Comment: yah you are write i will update it, thanks for mention that

Comment: could you update your question with what you update and the new error

Comment: Thanks Tim Lewis.
$area->city_id = $city->id; helps me lot.